# Infopath form is displyed as xml in a form library

Tags: infopath, form

I am trying to transfer some forms I have developed in the past in SP2010 environment to SP2013.

The problem is that when I create a form library in SP2013 the submitted form gets saved as XML file which cannot be opened through InfoPath form template.

Any thoughts on how can I resolve this?

Comment: what is the error message you get?

Comment: I do not get any, but the InfoPath doesn't open the submit form(it is in xml format). I am opening the form via notepad which makes it completely useless. In SP 2010, the form template in Infopath would automatically open the instance of the form in the form library.

Comment: have you published your form to the library you want it to open from?

Comment: This is administrator approved form. I am not sure that such procedure involves publishing a form to a form library. I have, however, published a form template to the form template library, and the form template opens fine.

Comment: so it works now?

Comment: No, it is not working. We believe that during the installation of the SharePoint 2013 services were not properly configured. We will switch to Office 365 and hopefully this will fix this issue.